# Enclosing column names from SQL script in quotes to use in python list

Tags: python, sql

More than once I've exported column names from a SQL script, e.g.

```
SELECT a, b, c from MyTable
```

to use in a list in python

```
MyColumns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The embuggerance is adding the quotes when there are many columns. Currently I paste the names into Excel, do text to columns, transpose and use formulas to add the quotes, then paste back into code.

Is there a better way?

Comment: what sql are you using. there are many ways.. What you have described is possibly the hardest, most long winded way I have heard of!

Comment: It is just SQL script, so I treat it as text.  Since you ask - at the moment I'm using a jupyter notebook to connect to MariaDB, so the SQL scripts are being run from jupyter.  I'm also using HeidiSQL to connect.

Comment: i have updated my answer for mariadb.. according to their documentation.. its a MYSQL DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you would do it using python using mariadb.

Change the user, password and database name.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

# enter the credentials
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='python_user', password='some_pass', database='some_database')

# create a cursor to access the DB
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

# Create an empty list to append queries to
columns = []

# loop over the desired columns, appending each one to the list
for column in cursor.execute("SELECT a, b, c from MyTable"):
    columns.append(column)

# check the output    
print(columns)
```

You can do any SQL query you like by putting what you would normally do inside the `cursor.execute()` command

if you just want to `INSERT` or `CREATE` you can do something like..

## create a table

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums
                  (title text, artist text, release_date text, 
                  publisher text, media_type text) 
              """)
```

or

## insert some data

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO albums VALUES ('Glow', 'Andy Hunter', '7/24/2012', 'Xplore Records', 'MP3')")

# save data to database
conn.commit()
```

Here is a link to the mariadb documentation for python..

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb

If you wish to add sql data to a list from a string you can implement the following..

some_sql_string = "a b c john ashu jimmy"

```
lst = []

for x in some_sql_string.split():
    lst.append(x)

print(lst)

['a', 'b', 'c', 'john', 'ashu', 'jimmy']
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion if I cannot execute the SQL and still want to code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. can you give an example?

Comment: With the SQL script I can copy paste and do the long winded way in Excel without relying on having the database connection.  So the example is - what to do if the database is not connected?  As it seems I can only print(columns) if the cursor connects and does the execution.

Comment: you mean save the sql query to an excel file?

Comment: The question is the same as above - except this time I cannot connect to the database.  In this case mariadb_connection will not be defined - however I still have the text of the SQL script to work with in python.

Comment: i have updated my answer.. if that is incorrect, please post a new question and put a link here and i will answer it better :)